# C++ function somehow prevents main from being invoked

Tags: c++, opencv

I encountered a strange issue in C++ and OpenCV2. The following code does not print "`I ran!`":

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

// Opens image as grayscale and saves it to save_dir
int grayscale_file(const cv::String &file_dir, const std::string &save_dir){
    cv::Mat fi = cv::imread(file_dir, cv::ImreadModes::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);// Loads image as grayscale

    return cv::imwrite(save_dir, fi);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::cout << "I ran!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*However* when I remove the code inside `grayscale_file`, it prints "`I ran!`":

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

// Opens image as grayscale and saves it to save_dir
int grayscale_file(const cv::String &file_dir, const std::string &save_dir){
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::cout << "I ran!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first piece of code prevent "`I ran!`" from being printed to the terminal, whereas the second piece of code doesnt?

**Edit:** Commenting some things out lead me to the issue of the `cv::imread` function. Removing the line that uses this lets the program run. I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries) that explains it pretty well. I'll find a debug library instead of the release that I think I was using.

Comment: Are you sure you did not get build errors with the first code? I don't see any reason for a run time error or UB especially since the function was never called.

Comment: What if you put in keyboard smash instead? I bet you have a build error.

Comment: @drescherjm It was able to compile just fine. It looks like whenever I just include OpenCV it breaks. Am I passing my arguments wrong?

Comment: Either it compiles, in which case the `main()` function runs, or it doesn't. Set a breakpoint in `main()` and run with tracing.

Comment: @JaMiT So sorry. Whenever I try to use it inside of the function it doesn't allow `main()` to be ran. I'll try and find out if there were any possible errors.

Comment: "it doesn't allow main() to be ran" is not a thing that happens. Run in a debugger. See where it actually goes. Maybe your library bombs out before `main()` can engage, sure, but you need to know what's up.

Comment: If there's a static variable somewhere it will be initialized before `main` starts. If that hangs then main might never start. If the static variable is part of the cv library it will only be included if there's a call that forces the library to be linked.

Comment: What you might be missing: many IDEs, when they are told to build and run, will *run the last version of the program that compiled, even if there was an error that prevented building the current source code*.

Comment: @TomTheCat Ah, you probably intended "include" in a more colloquial sense than `#include`. Good idea to stick to phrasing this as "use". ;)

Comment: @JaMiT My bad. Whenever I use `cv::imread` it doesn't exactly run `main()`. My issue was that I was using the release libraries instead of the debug libraries. Since I'm on Windows, it's going to be a rough time trying to get it to work.

Comment: MSVC builds in RelWithDebug mode even though Release is selected. Try adding `CV_IGNORE_DEBUG_BUILD_GUARD` to compile options. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166710/can-i-use-a-release-config-of-opencv-with-debug-config-of-my-app)

Comment: Make sure you use the same variant of the Microsoft VC runtime library during opencv build snd your build. You can see a lot of undefined behaviour from heap corruptions otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of head-scratching and research, I eventually figured out that my debugger was throwing an error at me (as pointed out in the comments). I was able to find info on fixing it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396369/error-during-startup-program-exited-with-code-0xc0000135), which lead me to believe that my libraries were *still* not properly linked.

I am not 100% sure on why or how the error came to be, or how I fixed it, but I essentially used MSYS2's library installer to install OpenCV via [this page](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-opencv). Information on the `pacman` command and installing the libraries was originally found [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).

My final code and `*.json` files are as follows:

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I\"C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\opencv4\"",
                "-L\"C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\"",
                "-lopencv_imgcodecs460",
                "-lopencv_highgui460",
                "-lopencv_core460",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/corrscii.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**c_pp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files/Cpp_Libs/OpenCV-MinGW-Build-OpenCV-4.5.5-x64/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "cppStandard": "c++23"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    cv::String img_path = "C:\\path\\to\\a_photo.png";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(img_path);

    if (img.empty()){
        std::cout << "Error: inputted file cannot be read" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps anybody who may come across it.